# listening to button clicks from another file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a button that acts like a checkbox, when you click it, it changes to show you that you have selected it, and vice versa to deselect.... on/off .. true/false.

Now I have imported it to the main `.dart`.. and called the button twice (passing different arguments to create a different text) to have two buttons.
How can I in `main.dart` file distinguish between the first button and the second button clicks and which one of them is on and off, and show the output:

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: [
          ButtonCheck('Text1'),
          ButtonCheck('Text2'),
Text('Button1 is '), // on or off
Text('Button2 is '),

        ],
      )),
    );
```

the button:that takes text arguments, something like this: --Using `GestureDetector` and containers for design purposes, the code is simplified--

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  ButtonCheck(
    this.text,
  );
  _ButtonCheckState createState() => _ButtonCheckState();
}

class _ButtonCheckState extends State<ButtonCheck> {
  String text;

  void initState() {
    text = widget.text;

    super.initState();
  }

  var _textStyle;

  void ActivateButton() {
    setState(() {
      _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green);
    });
  }

  void DeactivateButton() {
    setState(() {
      _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        if (_textStyle == TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red)) {
          ActivateButton();
        } else {
          DeactivateButton();
        }
      }),
      child: Text(
        '${text}',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: _textStyle,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use `GlobalKey` and pass `refresh` callback

```
GlobalKey _button1Key = GlobalKey();
...
class ButtonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  VoidCallback callback;
  ButtonCheck({Key key, this.text, this.callback}) : super(key: key);
...
void ActivateButton() {
    setState(() {
      isActive = true;
      _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green);
    });
    if (widget.callback != null) {
      widget.callback();
    }
  }
```

Step 2: You can pass `GlobalKey`

```
ButtonCheck(key: _button1Key, text: 'Text1', callback: refresh),
```

Step 3: You can show data with convert `ButtonCheckState` and get `attribue` `isActive`

```
Text('Button1 is ${(_button1Key.currentState as ButtonCheckState)?.isActive?.toString()}'),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  VoidCallback callback;
  ButtonCheck({Key key, this.text, this.callback}) : super(key: key);
  ButtonCheckState createState() => ButtonCheckState();
}

class ButtonCheckState extends State<ButtonCheck> {
  String text;
  bool isActive;

  @override
  void initState() {
    text = widget.text;
    super.initState();
  }

  var _textStyle;

  void ActivateButton() {
    setState(() {
      isActive = true;
      _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green);
    });
    if (widget.callback != null) {
      widget.callback();
    }
  }

  void DeactivateButton() {
    setState(() {
      isActive = false;
      _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red);
    });
    if (widget.callback != null) {
      widget.callback();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        if (_textStyle == TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red)) {
          ActivateButton();
        } else {
          DeactivateButton();
        }
      }),
      child: Text(
        '${text}',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: _textStyle,
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _button1Key = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _button2Key = GlobalKey();

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ButtonCheck(key: _button1Key, text: 'Text1', callback: refresh),
            ButtonCheck(
              key: _button2Key,
              text: 'Text2',
              callback: refresh,
            ),
            Text(
                'Button1 is ${(_button1Key.currentState as ButtonCheckState)?.isActive?.toString()}'), // on or off
            Text(
                'Button2 is ${(_button2Key.currentState as ButtonCheckState)?.isActive?.toString()}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```